# Find steps to sort unsorted string list

Tags: c++, sorting, c++20

Let's say that we have a list of strings and we want to find the steps (pair representing swaps to be made) to sort it. Here is my current implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

auto is_lexicographically_ordered = [](const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
};

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> find_unsorted(const std::vector<std::string> &list) {
    std::vector<std::string> cpy(list);
    std::vector<std::string> sorted(list);
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> result;

    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), is_lexicographically_ordered);

    // Cache indices for faster retrieval in loop
    auto index_in_cpy = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cpy.size(); ++i)
        index_in_cpy.insert({cpy.at(i), i});

    // Find mistmatched between sorted and current list
    auto it = std::mismatch(cpy.begin(), cpy.end(), sorted.begin());

    while (it.first != cpy.end()) {
        result.push_back(std::make_pair(*it.first, *it.second));

        auto new_it = cpy.begin() + index_in_cpy.at(*it.second);

        std::iter_swap(it.first, new_it);
        it = std::mismatch(++it.first, cpy.end(), ++it.second);
    }

    // Merging paths because for { c, a, b, d }, we would get { c, a }, { c, b } and { c, d }
    // but we only need to move c after d
    auto u = std::unique(result.rbegin(), result.rend(), [](const auto &p1, const auto &p2) {
        return p1.first == p2.first;
    });
    result.erase(result.begin(), u.base());

    return result;
}
```

and here is an example on how to run it:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    for (auto &item : find_unsorted({ "a", "c", "b", "d" })) {
        std::cout << "(" << item.first << ", " << item.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any feedback on how to improve runtime or storage space is welcome. Also, if you have more modern way of writing this (eg: range, etc.), feel free to recommend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Avoid copies of complex/big objects, especially if it involves a heap-allocation or anything similarly expensive.

   Just sort a list of indices.
2. Use views (`std::span`) instead of constant references. It results in a more flexible interface without additional cost.
3. Are you sure you want to return copies of pairs of objects, instead of indices?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you use the Ranges functions where appropriate.  For example, compare

> ```
>     std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), is_lexicographically_ordered);
> ```

with

```
    std::ranges::sort(sorted, is_lexicographically_ordered);
```

The latter is easier to read and understand.

---

Why do we need `is_lexicographically_ordered()` anyway?  That seems to be exactly the same as the default (`std::less<std::string>`).  The name is misleading; I expect any `is_x()` to be a *predicate*, i.e. returning `bool`.

---

Consider generating the list as you do the sorting (by recording the swaps you make as you sort), rather than calling `std::sort()` and then looking to see what's moved.  That might be easiest with insertion sort or similar.

Comment: Is using ranges simply for writing more modern c++ or there are other reasons ? For the generating list, could you give more details ?

Comment: Ranges code is often shorter and easier to read; that's why I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

## Make it more generic

Your function will work for `std::vector`s of `std::string`s, but what if you want to sort a regular array of `int`s? Or a `std::deque` of `std::chrono::time_point`s? You can do this by turning your function into a template.

It also helps to look at the declaration of [`std::ranges::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort), and copy most of it. You might want to keep the first parameter a `const` reference, and of course the return value should still be a container of swaps. I'd start with:

```
template<std::ranges::random_access_range R,
         class Comp = std::ranges::less,
         class Proj = std::identity>
requires std::sortable<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>, Comp, Proj>
auto find_unsorted(const R& list, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) {
    …
}
```

It doesn't require that many changes to make your function work with that. It helps to make an alias for the type of values the list holds:

```
using value_type = typename R::value_type;
```

And then you can copy the input and create the vector holding the output like so:

```
auto cpy = list;
auto sorted = list;
auto result = std::vector<std::pair<value_type, value_type>>();
```

Then you pass the parameters on to `std::ranges::sort()`:

```
std::ranges::sort(list, comp, proj);
```

This gives you a lot of benefits: the caller can now decide to pass a custom comparison and/or projection function, and it can pass any kind of container that can be sorted.

## Avoid making copies

A big problem with your function is that it makes lots of copies of the contents of `list`: `cpy` and `sorted` are two obvious copies, but `index_in_cpy` and `result` also contain copies of values stored in `list`. If the strings (or whatever type the values are) are very large, that will waste a lot of memory, and cost CPU cycles to copy.

Ideally, you will not make any copies of the elements in `list`. You can do this, for example, by having `sorted` store iterators into `list`, and then sort it using a custom projection function that returns the value pointed to by the iterator. That way it will still sort the iterators the way you want.

At the end you should have `result` hold pairs of iterators into `list`. The caller can then dereference them if they want to access the values pointed to.